# Cannot read files from hdfs in pyspark for Amazon EMR

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to make python program for Amazon EMR but i cannot read files from hdfs in it.
I am doing it like this:
Cluster config is following: Release: emr-5.25.0, hive 2.3.5, spark 2.4.3

At first i am starting shell script from computer not in cluster like this:

`aws emr add-steps ... --steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR .. Args=['s3://script.sh']`

Script is in s3 bucket.

Script doing some checks and copies files from s3 to cluster like this:

```
s3-dist-cp s3://some_file /mnt1/some_file
hdfs dfs -put /mnt1/some_file hdfs://home/hadoop/output/gzip
hdfs dfs -ls -h hdfs://home/hadoop/output/gzip (1)
```

Then script start python program like this:

`spark-submit ... --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster s3://script.py`

In python program i am doing something like this:

```
if __name__=="main":

    subprocess.check_output("hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://home/hadoop/output/gzip") #(2)
    sc = SparkContext()
    f = sc.binaryFiles("hdfs://home/hadoop/output/gzip") #(3)
    f.keys().foreach(some_fn)
```

My issue is that (1) works correctly and shows files in hdfs. 
(3) works correctly too, but (2) does not output anything, saying '[Errno 2] No such file or directory'.

What i am trying to do, is to modify python code since binaryFiles, as i understand, loads files contents into memory and splits it between nodes, but in this task i need to know only file names.

Comment: You can read the file on the S3 from the python code, why this long journey is needed?

Comment: script doing a lot of preparation work which cannot be made parallel. it should be done before spark starts it work. But even if i move it to python question stays the same - how i can write, read and list hdfs contents from pyspark on amazon emr?

Comment: The path of hadoop should be /user/hadoop/some_file.txt. Can you try that?